# Can we use website link as an URLScheme for deeplink

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking, url-scheme

I have to implement `deeplink` in my application. I have a product url which usually opens a product details page in web browser. But, now by using the same product url, I need to open my iOS app. I tried by adding a `deeplink` extracted from that product url. Say my product url is `https://www.mywebsite.com/product/details/xxxx`, I have added a `URLScheme` as my `website.com/product` also tried with `www.website.com/product` but it's not redirecting to app, it's going to website only. Can we add URLScheme as same as website base URL? Please help me on this.

Comment: Harsha, you can do it, for example think that your website name will be harsha.com.  You have to set harsha.com/apple-app-site-association file, check this, you have to upload this file and set this file with some options, you can set the path and App id, so if you give your appId and option, when you visit this website, it will automatically redirect to your application, and you can parse the website parameters in app, for example; www.harsha.com/itemId=3, you visit this website, in app delegate this will be notified, just parse the `itemId = 3`

Comment: Thanks @eemrah, I'm checking with my backend team.